# Find the number of occurrences of items in list inside a JSON

Tags: json, lodash

I've following JSON where I've ownerid with their car make. Is there a better way in lodash to get count by car makes from a predefined list.

Eg,

```
{
    "data": [
        {"ownerId":"00001", "make": "Honda"},
        {"ownerId":"00002", "make": "Nissan"},
        {"ownerId":"00003", "make": "Audi"},
        {"ownerId":"00004", "make": "Porsche"},
        {"ownerId":"00005", "make": "Honda"},
        {"ownerId":"00006", "make": "Honda"},
        {"ownerId":"00007", "make": "Audi"},
        {"ownerId":"00008", "make": "Volkswagen"},
        {"ownerId":"00009", "make": "Honda"},
        {"ownerId":"00010", "make": "Porsche"},
        {"ownerId":"00011", "make": "Volkswagen"}
    ]
}
```

Filter list for calculating count:

```
["Honda", "Audi", "Porsche"]
```

Expected result:

```
[{"Audi": 2}, {"Honda": 4}, {"Porsche": 2}]
```

There are other car makes in the input JSON but not considered since the filter list doesn't have it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find number of occurences of string elements in an Array using lodash or underscore js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371785/find-number-of-occurences-of-string-elements-in-an-array-using-lodash-or-undersc)

Comment: You need to adapt it, no solution would be copy/paste as your key is *make*

Comment: I know @LawrenceCherone but I believe the given solution is outdated. Seems like the answer given is what I needed. There is some issue when I used the actual JSON which needed to process. Will accept the answer when I find it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`_.countBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#countBy) to get and object of counts per make, and then [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#pick) the items you want:

```js
const cars = {"data":[{"ownerId":"00001","make":"Honda"},{"ownerId":"00002","make":"Nissan"},{"ownerId":"00003","make":"Audi"},{"ownerId":"00004","make":"Porsche"},{"ownerId":"00005","make":"Honda"},{"ownerId":"00006","make":"Honda"},{"ownerId":"00007","make":"Audi"},{"ownerId":"00008","make":"Volkswagen"},{"ownerId":"00009","make":"Honda"},{"ownerId":"00010","make":"Porsche"},{"ownerId":"00011","make":"Volkswagen"}]};

const list = ["Honda", "Audi", "Porsche"];

const result = _.pick(_.countBy(cars.data, 'make'), list);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly for the question which I asked.
Is there any way to get count as 0 if I add "Ferrari" to "list" and is not existing in cars?

Comment: Instead of pick, you can get reduce the list, get the counts from the object, and if the count doesn't exist, assign 0 instead: `const result = list.reduce((r, make) => {
  r[make] = counts[make] || 0;
  
  return r;
}, {});`

Comment: Following code seems to be working for me with default `0` values.
`const result = _(cars).countBy('make').pick(list).defaults(_(list).mapKeys().mapValues(function() { return 0; }).value());`

Comment: I'm very new to lodash. Do you know the difference between _. and _()?